# PHP send input values as parameters in method call

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP, trying to replicate a JavaBeans/JSF assignment...

I need to call a method in class Service that verify user name and password.

I have this php in the top of my index.php:

```
<?php 
include("Service.php");
$service = new Service();
if($_POST) {
    if (!$service->checkUser($_POST['name'], $_POST['password'])) {
        $error = "Username and password incorrect";
        echo $error;
    }
}?>
```

Mu form action calls it's own document:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
```

I have 2 input fields (name, password) like this:

My Service.php class has the function checkUser. It returns a String:

```
public function checkUser($name, $password) {
    foreach($this->users as $user) {
        if ($user->getName() == $name && $user->getPassword() == $password) {
            return "welcome.php";
        }
        else
            return "error.php";
    }
}
```

How can I use that String to use as navigation when form is submitted?

Answer (score 3):

Few issues:

1) `$POST` should be `$_POST`

2) Does `checkUser()` return a string containing the form action? As that's what your code is currently doing..?

It looks to me like you should be posting to a PHP script, probably the same filename that you are already in, and then call the `checkUser` method:

Form:

```
<form action="/" method="post">
..
</form>
```

Then in the PHP side:

```
<?php
if ($service->checkUser($_POST['name'], $_POST['password']))
{
  // do something
}
```

Comment: I would like to move the checkUser function _out of_ my index.php and into a separate class Service.php.

Yes, checkUser returns a string with a filename: welcome.php (if OK) or error.php (if not logged in).

So how do i call the function checkUser in Service-php in the action attrib.

Answer (score 0):

Left the action property empty and on the top of the page write the following code

```
  <?PHP
       if($_POST){
               if (!$service->checkUser($_POST['name'], $_POST['password'])){
                     $error = "Username and password incorrect";
               }
       }
  ?>
```

include your function here, And echo this error above the form